# Selector de base de datos PHP/SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion web que consiste en hacer unos calculos aritmeticos de los datos de una Base de Datos en mysql y mostrarlos con barras de progreso mediante progress bars. Actualmente el proyecto tiene 5 archivos:

- Login (contiene el query de conexion a mi cuenta de phpmyadmin)
- Operaciones (Selecciona los datos de la bbdd, hace las operaciones y guarda los resultados en variables de php)
- Index, variable1, variable2, variable3 (Son los 4 archivos que muestran las variables resultantes mediante barras de progreso).

Ahora quiero añadir un archivo mas que sea el selector de bases de datos. La idea seria que muestre la lista de bases de datos que hay en la cuenta de phpmyadmin en botones y que cuando el usuario haga clic en un boton pasen dos cosas:

- Que guarde el nombre de la bbdd del boton que ha hecho click para enviarselo al archivo del login y se conecte a la bbdd seleccionada. Para que el archivo de operaciones pueda hacer su trabajo en ESA bbdd y luego,
- Que envie al usuario a la pagina de index.php donde podra ver las variables resultantes para esa Base de Datos.

Aclaración: Las bases de datos son respuestas a un cuestionario, estos tienen la mismaa estructura y nombres de sus tablas y variables. Asi que lo unico que deberia pasar es que muestre resultados distintos segun el selector

He podido hacer la primera parte, tengo los botones y muestran el nombre de la bbdd, se puede hacer clic y te envia a la pagina de index, habiendo guardado el nombre y haciendo la conexion a la bbdd correctamente. Lo que pasa es que cuando cambio a una de las otros archivos, la variable se pierde y no se puede volver a conectar.

(Si se necesitan mas capturas del codigo puedo adjuntar)

Selector.php

```
<?php
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '','');
    /* check connection */
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $show_db = mysqli_query($con,"SHOW DATABASES"); 
    echo "<div class='grid-container selector'>
    <form id='select' method='post' action='index.php'>";
    $i=1;
    $array = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show_db)) {
         echo "<input type='submit' name='button'
         class='grid-item btn button selector-item' value=".$row[0].">";
        $i++;

        $array[] = $row[0];
        }

    echo "</div>";

    for($j=0;$j<=$i;$j++){
      if (isset($_POST['button'.$j.'']))
      {
        $db = $array[$j];
      }
  }     
?>
```

Login.php

```
<?php
$db = $_POST['button'];
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', $db);
/* check connection */
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: No es que haya entendido por completo la exposición del problema, pero puedes resolver esto fácilmente con Ajax. Incluso se podría simplificar, poniendo en la parte de `operaciones` un selector para indicar ya desde ahí a qué base de datos se van a ingresar/consultar los datos. Aunque tampoco entiendo por qué varias bases de datos y no sólo una ¿?

Answer (score 0):

prueba a guardar la variable(que vendría siendo el nombre de la base de datos) en una variable de sesión, guardándolo de la siguiente forma:

```
$_SESSION['bd'] = 'nombrebasededatos';
```

Para utilizar una variable de sesión primero debes iniciar la sesión añadiendo la función `session_start()` antes del `!DOCTYPE` en cada una de tus paginas. Todas las paginas en las que quieras crear o mostrar variables de sesión deben llevar dicha función antes de su cabecera.

Comment: Hola Diego, muchas gracias. He probado lo que me has dicho pero cuando navego por la app me dice que la session ya esta iniciada. Supongo que es porque el todas las paginas llevan un include 'login.php' y se 'pisan' entre ellos?

Comment: intenta colocando solo la variable `session_start()` en el login.php y en los demas php no lo pongas

Comment: He probado eso pero ahora me saltan estos errores:
`Notice: Undefined index: db in C:\xampp\..\login.php on line 3

Notice: session_start(): A session had already been started - ignoring in C:\xampp\..\login.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: db in C:\xampp\..\login.php on line 3

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\...operations.php on line 10
Error information from the database

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\..\operations.php on line 22`

Comment: Los errores que te arroja no son referidos a la sesion, ahi te esta informando que la variable db no esta definida, podrias adjuntarme una imagen de como dejaste tu codigo con el cambio que te dije a un principio? o algun link donde pueda ver tu codigo completo?